# CSS not working in default jekyll HTML

Tags: html, css, github, jekyll

I'm using jekyll to build a static webpage hosted on github, pulishing as gh-pages branch as default.

I've created `index.html` for unique changes, `theme.css` withing same directory: `../css`,

My css flie is not being executed and its not working, following is my code in each files..
file: default.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.baseurl}}/css/theme.css">

<title>Jai's Blog</title>

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>The BLOG</h1>

    {% includes nav.html %}
</header>

{{content}}

    <footer>
        <p>copyright Jai Sharma</p>
    </footer>

</body>
```

below is the css file code, which is not working with above html file.

```
body {

    background-color: #e74c3c;
}

.current {
    background-color: #000531;
}
```

Comment: Can you give a repository url, please ?

Comment: Replace `{{site.baseurl}}/css/theme.css` with the actual url and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The baseurl is only part of the url.

You should reference the entire url:

`{{ site.url }}/{{ site.baseurl }}/css/theme.css`

I think that the forward slash (`/`) is needed in this format.

Another way which I think works is:

`{{ site.url | append: site.baseurl }}/css/theme.css`

If you are happy with relative urls, the you could try:

`../css/theme.css`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you it helped, i was confused with the proper syntax.